# Thymeleaf form causes errors at th:field

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm very new to Thymeleaf and I'm trying to make a registration form but it keeps giving me error 500's when I try to add th: attributes to my form. I assume it has something to do with the form not seeing the UserModel but I can't be sure. I feel like I've tried everything so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my registration form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th=”http://www.thymeleaf.org” xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorate="layouts/defaultTemplate">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Register - AZSnowSports</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div layout:fragment="content">
        <form action="#" th:action="@{doRegister}" th:object="${userModel}" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"></td><td><h5 style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="*{firstName}">First Name Error</h5></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"></td><td><h5 style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}" th:errors="*{lastName}">Last Name Error</h5></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>EMail:</td><td><input type="email" th:field="*{email}"></td><td><h5 style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}">EMail Error</h5></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" th:field="*{address}"></td><td><h5 style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('address')}" th:errors="*{address}">Address Error</h5></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone Number:</td><td><input type="number" th:field="*{phoneNumber}"></td><td><h5 style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('phoneNumber')}" th:errors="*{phoneNumber}">Phone Number Error</h5></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" th:field="*{username}"></td><td><h5 style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}">Username Error</h5></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" th:field="*{password}"></td><td><h5 style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}">Password Error</h5></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my controller:

```
package com.azsnowsports.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import com.azsnowsports.model.UserModel;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegisterController {
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String display(Model model)
    {
        // Display the login form view
        model.addAttribute("title", "Register Form");
        return "register";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/doRegister")
    public String doRegister(@Valid UserModel userModel, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model)
    {
        //Check for validation errors
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        {
            model.addAttribute("title", "Register Form");
            return "register";
        }
        return "registerSuccess";
    }
}
```

And here's my user model:

```
package com.azsnowsports.model;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class UserModel {
    /**
     * The user's first name
     */
    @NotNull(message="FirstName is a required field.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 32, message="First Name must be between 1 and 32 characters.")
    private String firstName;
    /**
     * The user's last name
     */
    @NotNull(message="Last name is a required field.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 32, message="Last name must be between 1 and 32 characters.")
    private String lastName;
    /**
     * The user's email
     */
    @NotNull(message="EMail is a required field.")
    private String email;
    /**
     * The user's address
     */
    @NotNull(message="Address is a required field.")
    private String address;
    /**
     * The user's phone number
     */
    @NotNull(message="Phone Number is a required field.")
    private int phoneNumber;
    /**
     * The user's username
     */
    @NotNull(message="Username is a required field.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 32, message="Username must be between 1 and 32 characters.")
    private String username;
    /**
     * The user's password
     */
    @NotNull(message="Password is a required field.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 32, message="Password must be between 1 and 32 characters.")
    private String password;
    
    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param firstNameVal The first name of the user
     * @param lastNameVal The last name of the user
     * @param emailVal The email of the user
     * @param addressVal The address of the user
     * @param phoneNumber The phone number of the user
     * @param usernameVal The username for the user
     * @param passwordVal The password for the user
     */
    public UserModel(String firstNameVal, String lastNameVal, String emailVal, String addressVal, 
            int phoneNumberVal, String usernameVal, String passwordVal)
    {
        this.firstName = firstNameVal;
        this.lastName = lastNameVal;
        this.email = emailVal;
        this.address = addressVal;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumberVal;
        this.username = usernameVal;
        this.password = passwordVal;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return the firstName
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    /**
     * @param firstName the firstName to set
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the lastName
     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    /**
     * @param lastName the lastName to set
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    /**
     * @return the address
     */
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    /**
     * @param address the address to set
     */
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    /**
     * @return the phoneNumber
     */
    public int getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @param phoneNumber the phoneNumber to set
     */
    public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @return the username
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    /**
     * @param username the username to set
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Heres a screenshot of my file structure:
[image: fileStructure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `model.addAttribute("userModel", new UserModel());` into the root map of the model so it now looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public String display(Model model)
    {
        // Display the login form view
        model.addAttribute("title", "Register Form");
        model.addAttribute("userModel", new UserModel());
        return "register";
    }
```

This fixed it and it runs fine now!